# Assets for ExpressJS

Tags: css, node.js, express

ExpressJS noob here. How do I call images stored in **/public/images/** directory to my **/public/stylesheets/styles.css**

The following does not seem to work

```
.home-bg {
    background-image:url('../images/bg.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Could also just use `"/public/images/bg.jpg"`

Comment: please add your app.configure function. (relevant parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using express like this sample:

### app.js

```
// config
app.configure(function() {
    //..

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    //..
}
```

### Explanation

> `express.static`, is responsible for serving the static assets and the
>   argument refers to the root directory from which the static assets are
>   to be served.

It does not refer to the path on your web page. refers to the directory in nodejs project. So we add __dirname, then the folder is relative to app.js

### In summary:

if, `__dirname + '/public'` becomes in your `http://www.example.com/`
then `/public/images` becomes `http://www.example.com/images`

- [app.use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) reference
- [express.static](http://expressjs.com/api.html#express.static) reference
- [__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) reference

#### So CSS should be:

```
.home-bg {
    background-image:url('/images/bg.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you simply missing quotes on your url?, possible css error?

```
.home-bg {
    background-image:url('../images/bg.jpg');
}
```

edit:  heh, SO even formats it cute.

Comment: oops forgot to include that. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: is .home-bg simply a <body class="home-bg"> type thing on your page?

Comment: Nope, but I figured it out! Forgot to add height and width...it's been a while.

Comment: I was going to say, express paths aren't super complicated